# How to dismiss flutter autocomplete popup?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

The AutoComplete widget will automatically popup the dropdown list every time you clicked in the textfield. The problem is the popup cannot be dismissed unless you deliberately input some wrong words or select one item in the popup list. This leads to unwanted result.

You can check this behavior in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/7cb153e960dbb167e19862506b3de374?null_safety=true) or on the official document.

I expect the popup can be dismissed by hitting the esc key or clicking outside the popup, so that I can see the import thing underneath.

Has I missed something or it's simply a bug?

Answer (score 0):

from source code , they are three conditions to show a options view

```
bool get _shouldShowOptions {
    return _focusNode.hasFocus && _selection == null && _options.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

it seems that unfocus the underlying textfield is the simplest solution